# Py2Exe lost sys.stdin error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

I have a very simple script, that creates a file as big as the user wants:

```
from uuid import uuid4

global ammount
ammount = None

def randbyte():
    l = []
    a = uuid4().hex
    for char in a:
        l.append(str(char))
    return l[6]

def randkb():
    a = ''
    for num in range(0, 32):
        a = a + uuid4().hex
    return a

def randmb():
    a = ''
    for num in range(0, 32):
        a = a + randkb()
    return a

exit = False
print('##### DATA DUMP v1 #####')
while exit == False:
    ammount = input('AMMOUNT OF DATA TO DUMP IN BYTES >> ')
    try:
        ammount = int(arg)
        print('DUMPING...')
        b = int(ammount % 32)
        a = int(ammount - b)
        c = int(a / 32)
        with open('dump.txt', 'w') as file:
            for num in range(0, c):
                print('KB')
                a = uuid4().hex
                file.write(a)
            for num in range(0, b):
                print('B')
                a = randbyte()
                file.write(a)
        print('COMPLETED')
    except ValueError:
        print('ARGUMENT MUST BE AN INTEGER')
```

It works fine when I run it through the interpreter. However, when I put it through py2exe, I always get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 31, in <module>
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```

My setup.py is this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {'bundle_files': 2, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "d.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

I searched for a while but couldn't find any solutions that apply in this particular case. Did I miss something? Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Not sure if you realise, but `randmb()` only generates 32KiB, not 1MiB.

Comment: @mhawke That really doesn't help

Comment: Sorry for being unhelpful. Nevertheless, it is a problem in your code that you may not have been aware of, and that is why it is posted as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks for pointing it out, but i really need to find a solution to my problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a windows GUI app for which there is no stdin. You probably want a console app which does have stdin, so you need to set it up accordingly. Try replacing `windows` with `console`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {'bundle_files': 2, 'compressed': True}},
    console = ["d.py"],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Or possibly it should be `console=[{'script': 'd.py'}],` - I'm not sure what difference there is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Python 3 code for the py2exe `setup.py` file (which includes path to Mozilla Firefox driver, [download it from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and place it in folder of your script, the code also sets the custom icon "*favicon.ico*", 64x64px for the console app):

```
from distutils.core import setup;
import py2exe;
data_files = [("selenium/webdriver/firefox", ['geckodriver.exe'])];

setup(
   name="App Name",
   version="1.0",
   description="App Description",
   author="Author",
   author_email="",
   url="",
   options = 
   {
    "py2exe": 
            {
                "bundle_files": 1,
                "skip_archive": True,
                "optimize": 2
            }
   }, 
     data_files=data_files,
     console = [{             
        "script":"app.py",           
        "icon_resources": [(1, "favicon.ico")],
        "dest_base":"",
        "zipfile": None,
        }]
  )
```